# How can I tell if my palm oil is rancid?

Tags: spoilage

I've purchased a sustainable brand and have read about it's nutrition and use.  It was stored in a cool, dark cupboard and I haven't used any yet.  I opened the jar last week and it has a sharpish smell.

Comment: I'd just give it a taste. A little oil rancidity is unlikely to kill me, it's just oxidized double bonds and crosslinking on edible long chain fatty acids. If the stuff smells bad *and* tastes bad, I'd call it bad.

Comment: Is this refined or red palm oil?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Yes, as far as I know, rancid oil is not toxic to eat, although it might be unpalatable.